# Give permissions to a Windows 8 app to block another app

Tags: permissions, windows-8, block

I'm trying to make my windows 8 app block another app from being launched or launch another app depending on user settings. For example block a browser from opening and launch a media player.

Is this possible?

Comment: can you provide a little more context on your scenario?  [protocol activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452686.aspx) might provide an alternative to what you're looking to accomplish

Comment: I'm trying to make an app that allows me to enter into a "focus mode". I want a user to define which applications are inspiring and which are distracting launching the first automaticly and blocking the last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Windows Store apps are running in sandboxed environment and you definitely cannot block any app from being used from another app.